# How can point to correct snapshot id of SL Endurance Replica Volume?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm currently using manual snapshots and updating their 'notes' field to contain a timestamp value in order to coordinate dozens of drives snapshots to be restored to at the same time.

I've now added Replication volumes and schedules to each of these drives and want the capability to restore to a specific grouping of snapshots ( across all drives ) however the 'notes' field I populate on the original volumes snapshots is not replicated across to the failover site.  Is there any workaround to this? How can I get the correspondence between snapshot id's and their replicas snapshot id's?

Answer (score 0):

The note should be populated in the replica, actually this is an issue in softlayer and it is reported unfourtunally there is no a estimated time for the fix :(.

Regards